# Can dplyr remove all dots from as.character string?

Tags: r, database, string, dplyr

Lets say I have a set of dates

```
> p
       birth
1 22.12.1946
2 01.08.1948
3 02.11.2028
4 18.11.1953
5 28.03.1948
```

Is there a `dplyr` solution to remove all dots?

I tried

```
p %>% mutate(birth = str_replace(birth, ".", ""))
```

Data

```
p <- structure(list(birth = c("22.12.1946", "01.08.1948", "02.11.2028", 
"18.11.1953", "28.03.1948")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need `fixed` wrapped or escape (`\\.`) the dot as `.` in regex matches any character and not the literal `.`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
p %>%
     mutate(birth = str_remove_all(birth, fixed(".")))
```

-output

```
#   birth
#1 22121946
#2 01081948
#3 02112028
#4 18111953
#5 28031948
```

NOTE: while `str_replace_all` would work as well, the wrapped `str_remove` would be a compact option

---

It is easier to convert to `Date` class first and then do the `format`

```
format(as.Date(p$birth, "%d.%m.%Y"), "%d%m%y")
#[1] "221246" "010848" "021128" "181153" "280348"
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer as soon as SO let me. Quick spin-off question, `p$birth` is `ddmmyyyy`. Is it possible to easily convert to `ddmmyy`?